# Handler.post(Runnable) doesn't work sometime

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I create a Handler in Service `onCreate()`

```
mHandler = new Handler();
```

And then I use this handler to post messages (Runnable) to Acivity

```
mHandler.post(Runnable);
```

It works sometime and fails at other time. Not sure why would same call will fail?
Is there any way that it can be guaranteed to execute?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of "fails at other time"? Does it crash? :-)

Comment: what is the stacktrace when it fails?

Comment: No crash, no exception. The runnable simply doesn't execute randomly. I am sure there must be some reason but until I know that, I call it random.

Comment: what does `post()` return? did you check that?

Comment: No, I was not checking that. But just adding that check can make any difference? It seems it does. I just added and It seems to be working now!! Random!

Comment: so when does it return `false`?

Comment: I has not returned false so far in last few tests but I will keep observing and post when it does. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173046/discussion-between-iuq-and-pskink).